Errors decoding a binary image file using blob & window.btoa in tauri with Vue3
Demo:
components/imgDecode.vue:
<script setup>
import { nextTick, ref } from "vue";
import markdownIt from "markdown-it";
import { invoke, convertFileSrc } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri';
import { resolve, resourceDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
import { readBinaryFile } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";

const md = markdownIt();
md.set({ html: true });
const md_context = ref();

// an arbitrary image in the /img dir in my project
let img_path = "E:/myProjects2/tauri_vue/mdren/img/a-1-01.png";
// convert the image file from Uint8Array to string, then solve it with window.btoa
const contents = await readBinaryFile(img_path);
const str_contents = () => {
  let binary = "";
  let len = contents.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return binary;
}
let src = window.btoa(str_contents);

// an async logics
currentLogics();

async function currentLogics() {
  try {
    // process the markdown file first
    await solveMd();
    // re-render the images after the DOM has changed
    nextTick(() => {
      reloadImg();
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function solveMd() {
  md_context.value = await md.render("$\\xRightarrow{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}$\n\n<img id='img-to-remove' src='../img/a-1-01.png'>");
  // ignore the xRightarrow line, the markdown-it-katex cannot stretch it properly, and it's temporarily fixed with other methods
}

async function reloadImg() {
  console.log("function called");
  let img_element = document.querySelectorAll("#img-to-remove");
  console.log(img_element);
  img_element.forEach(async (element) => {
    element.src = "data:image/png;base64," + src;
  });
}
</script>

<template>
    <div v-html="md_context"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>

App.vue:
<script setup>
import imgDecode from "./components/imgDecode.vue";
</script>

<template>
    <Suspense>
        <resolveData />
    </Suspense>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>

I wrote a markdown rendering tool using tauri + Vue3 + markdown-it, but there are images in the markdown files, the contents are binded to the pages with v-html, so all the assets resolved using relative routes.
The images are rendered properly with npm run tauri dev, with a localhost built in the main directory of the project. However with npm run tauri build, this won't work, the images cannot render mainly due to the security policy.
Then I revised the tauri.conf.json as the ConvertFileSrc shows, setting the tauri.security.csp as "csp": "default-src 'self'; img-src '*' asset: https://asset.localhost", where the '*' is set as other blogs suggests (actually it does not work with 'self' either), and the images still won't show.
Then I tried to use the Rust backend to read the file and send it to the frontend, using the blob to create a url, however the image seems broken, but the img src in dev tools seemed proper.
Afterwards I tried the tauri/api/fs. First, setting the tauri.allowlist.fs in the tauri.conf.json to:
    "fs": {
        "all": true,
        "scope": ["D:/**", "E:/**"]
    }

which allows it to read all the files in the disks, then set the csp to: "csp": "asset:". The main logics to prosess the image is:
let img_path = "E:/myProjects2/tauri_vue/mdren/img/a-1-01.png";
const contents = await readBinaryFile(img_path);
const str_contents = () => {
  let binary = "";
  let len = contents.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return binary;
}  // contents: Uint8Array -> string
let src = window.btoa(str_contents);  // window.btoa: string -> url

// ...

// call reloadImg after the DOM has changed, re-render the <img id="img-to-remove" ...>
async function reloadImg() {
  console.log("function called");
  let img_element = document.querySelectorAll("#img-to-remove");
  console.log(img_element);
  img_element.forEach(async (element) => {
    element.src = "data:image/png;base64," + src;
  });
}

which is shown at the beginning of the question. These attempts all worked well except the last step, the img src all seemed correct, but the images are all broken. I guess this problem might be caused with the readBinaryFile and the attempts using the Rust backend to read the file. The csp and rendering all passed my tests.

You never actually call str_contents? You just hand the function off to window.btoa.

@Botje Thanks, it seems to be the case. But the problem has been solved using blob, so apologize that I won't test what you mentioned.
